# javamail idle creates multiple threads

Tags: java, push, jakarta-mail

I have implemented an idle javamail monitor similar to the example in the documentation. However, sometimes two or more simultaneous threads of the idle are triggered, which causes the folder.idle() of the for not to stop running. This causes that a lot of network is consumed and they do not stop.

Is there any way I can detect that there is already an imap thread so that another thread does not start?

Here is an example of what you print in the log

```
10-21 14:22:11.595 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6764,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.595 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.595 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.596 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.596 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6764,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.596 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.596 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6755,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.597 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.597 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6764,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.597 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.598 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.598 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.598 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6755,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.599 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.599 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.599 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.599 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.600 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.600 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.600 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.600 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.602 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.606 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.607 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.607 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6764,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.607 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.607 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6755,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.608 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.608 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6764,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.608 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.608 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.609 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.609 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6755,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.609 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.609 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6755,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.610 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.610 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6764,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.610 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.610 8095-22625/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6751,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.610 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
10-21 14:22:11.610 8095-23671/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: wait to be not idle: Thread[Thread-6755,5,main]
10-21 14:22:11.611 8095-24908/X I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: waitIfIdle: idleState 2
```

I'm only subscribed to a single folder inbox. I really do not understand why several threads are created ...

this is the code...

```
props =  getServerProperties(account.getEmail(), false);
    session = null;
    store = null;
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    store =  session.getStore("imap");

    if(!store.isConnected())
    {
        store.connect(account.getEmail(), account.getPassword());
    }
    folderInbox = store.getFolder("inbox");

if(folderInbox == null || !folderInbox.exists())
{
    internalError();
    return;
}

folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);


SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(unReviewFlagTerm, unDeleteFlagTerm);
Message[] allmessages =folderInbox.search(searchTerm, folderInbox.getMessages());

...

    try {
        folderInbox.expunge();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

folderInbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {

    public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
        Log.d("Monitor new message", lastNewMessage.toString());
        Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();

    }

});

int freq = Integer.parseInt("180000"); // 3 minutes
boolean supportsIdle = false;
try {
    if (folderInbox instanceof IMAPFolder) {
        IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder)folderInbox;
        f.idle();
        supportsIdle = true;
    }
} catch (FolderClosedException fex) {
    internalError();
    supportsIdle = false;
    throw fex;
}catch (MessagingException mex) {
    supportsIdle = false;
}
for (;;) {
    if (supportsIdle  && folderInbox instanceof IMAPFolder) {
        IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder)folderInbox;
        f.idle();
    }else{
        Thread.sleep(freq);
        folderInbox.getMessageCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you're using threads, how many folders you have open, etc.?  Are you using the IdleManager class?  Or are you just calling the IMAPFolder.idle method?  The idle method never creates threads.  IdleManager uses an ExecutorService to create threads.  JavaMail events are delivered on a separate thread per Folder by default.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the code I use to start the idle. Please check it. Thank you

Comment: Are you calling that code more than once?  If you call it once it should only be using two threads.

Comment: Yes, I use it in an Android service, which could be called several times. Now how could I destroy the threads that have javamail assets to start them again? Or know that there is someone active to not create another?

Comment: If you close the folder, the idle method will throw an exception terminating the loop and thus allow the thread to terminate.

Comment: Thanks I resolved with your comment, subscribing to the OnDestroy event of the service and closing the folder and the session, although not entirely because I will never be sure if there is a thread running yet :(